# Delete from hash table linear probing

Tags: time-complexity, hashtable

What is the best way to remove an entry from a hashtable that uses linear probing?i know that One way to do this would be to use a flag to indicate deleted elements? Are there any ways better than this ?myabe by reducing spaces between values?
What is the time-complexity?

Comment: Please show your research effort: edit and put your code in the question.